# Give permissions to multiple users to use app script across multiple google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm not sure if this can be accomplished or not, need some guidance to determine the best solution.

I've a master google sheet with an app script attached to it that performs multiple functions on that sheet, the master sheet is a template and the sheets we use are copies of the master template. the problem with that is that when a new sheet is created from that master, every user has to approve permission to the app script for that sheet.

My question is can I give multiple users permissions to all created sheets so that they can use the appscript without having to authorize it?

I know that the best way is create the appscript as a cloud script, but the sheets are already created so I was looking for a second alternative, Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your situation from your question. About `the problem with that is that when a new sheet is created from that master, every user has to approve permission to the app script for that sheet.`, can you provide your current script? And, in this case, who is the owner of copied Spreadsheet? Or, do you want to make users copy a sheet in Google Spreadsheet to the same Google Spreadsheet? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I am the owner of the sheets, but even me when a new sheet is created I get a prompt saying Authorization Required, A script attached to this document needs your permission to run, I have to click on continue login to google and authorize the script access, I had to do this once. but this has to be done for every sheet, and every user has to do the same, I added a screenshot of the prompt to the question

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that you are the owner of Spreadsheet. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: I have a master sheet with a script attached to it, this sheet acts as a template to create multiple copies of this sheet, so whenever a new copy is created any user even me the owner has to give google permission to use the script for every sheet created from the template, my question is how can I give myself access to all those sheets and scripts without having to give permission to every sheet separately, I hope this clears my point